# my Ajax function code always returns error

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

i'm working with CodeIgniter, and my problem is that when i try to send a string to my controller ( with Ajax )so it includ it in an other string then return it, i obtain an error. the JQuery library is successfully loaded by the way.
here's my code. i really don't know what's wrong whit it.
 - myView.php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

 <title>myView</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/jquery.js' ?>"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
  $('#bttn').click(function()
  {
   var variable = $('#name').val();
   $.ajax(
   {
    type:'POST' , 
    data:{ name : variable } , 
    url:'<?php echo site_url('myController/message') ?>',
    success:function(result)
    {
     $('#result').html(result);
    },
    error: function() 
    {
         $('#result').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
        }
   });
  });
 });
 </script>

</head>

<body>

 name : &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
 <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"/>
 <input type="button" value="Submit" id="bttn"/>
 <h1 id="result"></h1>

</body>

</html>
```

- myController.php:

```html
<?php

class MyController extends CI_Controller
{
 public function index()
 {
  $this->load->view('myView');
 }

 public function message()
 {
  $name = $this->input->post('name');
  return 'Good evening Mr' . $name . '. I\'m Dr Hannibal Lecter';
 }
}

?>
```

Comment: You have console in browser. In case of error, you should receive error message in console with response code from server. Use this as starting point.

Comment: i get this message in the console:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://[::1]/AjaxTest/index.php/myController/message. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Are you on https maybe? This happens when you are on https and you are trying to go to http.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX expects string that is echoed from PHP

```
// echo "Good evening Mr $name. I'm Dr Hannibal Lecter';

public function message()
{
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    echo 'Good evening Mr' . $name . '. I\'m Dr Hannibal Lecter';
}
```

Comment: i solved the problem. :) . and what you just said wasn't the only error in my code. actually there was a header missing in the controller ( header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");)

Comment: I could propose solution regarding code you provided only. Check [this article](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) which can help you solve many problems by your own, but also will help you to ask as appropriate as it can be.